# Exception Value: _getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-settings

I don't what's the problem, i tried everything but never understood, what should i do in this scenario, please take a look

**Setting.py**
When i am doing this like that:

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    
    MEDIA_URL ='/images/'
    MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

it is showing this error

```
    ERRORS:
    ?: (staticfiles.E001) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting is not a tuple or list.
            HINT: Perhaps you forgot a trailing comma?
```

**Setting.py**
When i am doing this like that:

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
    
    MEDIA_URL ='/images/'
    MEDIA_ROOT =  [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images'),]
```

it is showing this error

```
    TypeError: _getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list
    [17/Mar/2021 13:27:59] "POST /admin/admission/personal/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 211689
```

anyone who could help??

Answer (score 0):

try

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]

MEDIA_URL ='/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT =  [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '*yourappname*/static/images'),]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MEDIA_URL ='/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images/')
```

The difference is only the `/` at the end of `images` i.e. `images/`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I removed this [] bracket, and it worked for me!

Problem: `MEDIA_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')]`

Solved for me: `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`

Just remove the [] bracket

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34462763)